# Coredata and automatic sorting of relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship

I have a managed object tour which has a number of points.
When I load the points to show them in a table, I use as my data tour.points.

Each point has a field 'level' indicating the order in which they should appear.
How can I make tour.points to sort automatically according to point.level?

Do I need to do a separate fetch with a sort description, or is there a direct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to populate a table view with Core Data is a `NSFetchedResultsController`. The FRC has a fetch request to which you can attach a predicate and sort descriptors.

There is some readily available sample code that you can copy from the Xcode templates when checking "Use Core Data".

In the fetched results controller creation method, add the predicate and sort descriptor. I am assuming you are fetching an entity called `Point` which has a to-one relationship to `Tour`.

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tour = %@", tourObject];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor 
    sortDescriptorWithKey:@"level" ascending:YES]];
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering if there would be a way of 'annotating' or so, like with JPA. But an extra request is not a problem, I have the functions already there anyway.

Comment: I do not understand "annotating" in this context.

Comment: In JPA you can annotate a field like  @OrderBy("lastname ASC"), so the field is automatically sorted when called upon. Saves have to do an extra query.

Comment: That is not applicable to Core Data because there are no "fields". It is common misconception to mistake attributes of entities in the object graph with "fields" of "tables" in a relational database. Instructive: [What Core Data Is Not](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009296-SW4)

Answer (score 0):

Up to my experience, I believe you would have to do a separate sort. As a reference of things you can do with NSPredicate for filtering arrays:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2013/10/21/ios-objective-c-filtering-a-nsarray-using-nspredicate.aspx

What I expect you will have to do will be something of this sort:

```
NSSortDescriptor *level = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"level" ascending:YES];
NSArray *pointSortedByLevel  = [results sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:level, nil]];
```

where results is your NSArray of Points found in your object Tour